# Cardinality of sets 2015

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A,B \subset\left\{1,2,3,\ldots\right\}$ be disjoint sets and let the number of elements ,$n(A)=m ,n(B)=k.$ Then what is $n(A+B) ?$ where we define $$A+B=\left\{i+j:i\in A,j\in B\right\}.$$ Any hints please?

Comment: It depends greatly on $A$ and $B$. It's obviously at most $mk$, and one can prove that it's at least $m+k-1$.

Comment: What does the "2015" in the title have to do with the question? Is there something missing?